# value of $x^3 - 6x^2 + 6x$ when $x$ is an expression involving radicals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

> If $x = 2 + 2^{\frac13} + 2^{\frac23}$, then what is the value of $x^3 - 6x^2 + 6x$?

How would I solve it? Surely plugging in is one way, but there's got to be some other way.

Comment: Why? Plugging in is a simple exercise. Of course, you can factor out x

Comment: @M.B.The source of this questions had a lot of difficult and tricky questions and this question is the last one...so there has to be some clever way of doing it...

Comment: @M.B. I have tried factoring out x and then plugging in...the answer comes 2, but it's quite boring

Comment: Right, ok. I see the trick now:)

Comment: Or.. Did not help that much, but it simplifies somewhat to write the sum of 2s as the sum of a geometric series.

Comment: Another way is to use field theory. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4811203/589

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x=2+2^{\frac13}+2^{\frac23}\implies (x-2)^3=(2^{\frac13}+2^{\frac23})^3$

$\implies x^3-8-6x^2+12x=2+4+6(x-2)=6x-6$

$\implies x^3-6x^2+6x=2$

Comment: And that's why I hate plugging in...

Answer (score 0):

You can factor it as $2(x-1)^3 - x^3 + 2$.  Since $(x-1)\left(2^{1/3}-1\right) = 1$ and $x\left(1-2^{-1/3}\right) = 1$ we get $$\left(\frac{2^{1/3}}{2^{1/3}-1}\right)^3 - \left(\frac{1}{1-2^{-1/3}}\right)^3 + 2.$$  So the left two terms cancel out.