# Find the value of $f(x)$ for $x = 2 + 2^{2/3} + 2^{1/3}$

Tags: functions, polynomials, quadratics, cubics

If $x = 2 + 2^{2/3} + 2^{1/3}$, then find the value of $f(x)=x^3 - 6x^2 + 6x$.

I am unable to get to the answer - end up with more than one term. Please help me solve this!

Comment: May be answer contain more than one term.

Comment: @Nilan - actually buddy i knew the answer was 2 :)

Comment: Already http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739174/value-of-x3-6x2-6x-when-x-is-an-expression-involving-radicals

Comment: @Macavity Oops! I should have performed a thorough search. Thanks for pointing it out friend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Letting $t=2^{1/3}\Rightarrow t^3=2$, we have
$$(x-2)^3=(t^2+t)^3$$$$\Rightarrow x^3-6x^2+12x-8=t^6+3t^5+3t^4+t^3=4+6t^2+6t+2.$$
Then, we have
$$\begin{align}x^3-6x^2+6x&=(6t^2+6t+6)+8-6x\\&=6t^2+6t+14-6(t^2+t+2)\\&=14-12\\&=2.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

We have $$x-2=2^{\frac23}+2^{\frac13}$$

Cubing we get, $$x^3-3x^2(2)+3x(2^2)+2^3=(2^{\frac23})^3+(2^{\frac13})^3+3\cdot2^{\frac23}\cdot2^{\frac13}(2^{\frac23}+2^{\frac13})$$

$$\iff x^3-6x^2+12x+8=2+2^2+6(x-2)$$

Can you take it home from here?

Comment: @MohitSingh, How about this?

Comment: Hey buddy I guess you mistakenly copied the question wrong - it is x-2 = 2^2/3 + 2^1/3 and not "2^2/3 + 2^2/3". Thanks for taking interest though! :)

Comment: @MohitSingh, Hope you understood the typo which has been rectified now