# Evaluating $x^3-18x^2+90x$, where $x= 6 + 6^{2/3}+ 6^{1/3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, arithmetic

> If $x= 6 + 6^{2/3}+ 6^{1/3}$,
> then find the value of $x^3-18x^2+90x$

*My try:*

I tried like directly substituting the value but it proved to be quite tedious and then I tried to take $6^{\frac{1}{3}}$ common but it didn't either.

Comment: I'm sure there must be better approach, but the algebra/arithmetic might go quicker if you rewrite the value of $x$ as $6^{2/3}(6^{-1/3} + 1 + 6^{1/3}).$ Still seems rather tediously pointless though (using my suggested rewrite), so that's surely not what is intended.

Comment: Recognize that $x^3-18x^2+90x=(x-6)^3-18x+216$

Comment: Just factor it out using laws of exponents.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using field theory. Perhaps not in the spirit of the question but fun anyway.

Let $\theta=6^{\frac{1}{3}}$ and consider $K=\mathbb Q(\theta)$, a cubic extension of $\mathbb Q$ having basis $\{1,\theta,\theta^2\}$.

With respect to this basis, the linear map $\mu: t \mapsto xt$ is given by this matrix:
$$
X=\begin{pmatrix} 6 & 6 & 6 \\ 1 & 6 & 6 \\ 1 & 1 & 6 \end{pmatrix}
$$
The characteristic polynomial of $X$ is $t^3 - 18 t^2 + 90 t - 150$ and so $x^3-18x^2+90x=150$.

The point here is that $x$, $\mu$, and $X$ satisfy exactly the same set of polynomials.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1841969/589

Answer (score -1):

Here's my attempt at this:

Using the comment from @Vasili, we can plug $6+6^{\frac13}+6^{\frac23}$ in for $x$ right away to get$$(x-6)^3-18x+216=(6^{1/3}+6^{2/3})^3-6\cdot3\cdot(6+6^{1/3}+6^{2/3})+216\\42+216+18+108+18\sqrt[3]6+18\sqrt[3]6+18\sqrt[3]{36}\\=384+36\sqrt[3]6+18\sqrt[3]{36}$$which is the value that you need to solve this question.

Comment: No, correct answer is $150$

Comment: @Leox I'll check quickly to see where I went wrong